# SQL find changes values and update in a separate table

Tags: sql

I hope someone could help me out. I am a beginner in SQL and currently learning.

I have a table with a group of employees as in the image shown. Each week an employee from one team changes to a different team.

[image]

Now, how can I retrieve only the changed data from one week to another week in a separate table. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why move data around?

Comment: @Eric it's been said many times before. don't be a jerk to newcomers. is it your purpose at this site to help or what else? more polite way of saying things goes long way. I also don't see anything wrong with his question. he doesn't know how to do it so he came here to ask. that is what this website is for, isn't it?

Comment: @MarianP He could at least try something even though it doesn't work at all.  it's better than no attempt at all.

Comment: @Eric you are too harsh. I think if someone is really new, use your knowledge to direct him.

Comment: What version and flavor of SQL?

Comment: Easiest way would be to look at the `Last Update` date. But your data shows an earlier date in Week2 for `Employee ID` 3, despite no other changes.

Comment: Actually I take my previous response back. A _much easier_ thing to do would be to simply copy whatever data changes into the new table at the same time you move a person from one team to another.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for being very supportive. To answer the questions: @eric I receive a file each week with a table of employees, supervisors. These changes each week so they send a refreshed version. Currently, I just copy this every week and store in a database - the challenge what I have is that a lot of duplicate data exist week by week meaning those who have not changed week on week I still carry them. Hence, I wanted to know is there any efficient way to append only the changed data from previous week.

Comment: @marianp thanks for being kind and welcoming :)

Comment: @Shawn the issue what I have is identifying the changed data and the corresponding employee with supervisor as each week I carry a lot of duplicates data.

Comment: @TSan So is historical data kept in the table? Without historical data, you won't be able to tell what changed.